# References not being displayed in output file by TexStudio

Tags: pdftex, cross-referencing, natbib

I recently started using LaTeX to complete my research thesis. My .tex file compiles fine, but the output file is not as expected:

1. **References are not displayed in the output file**. To trouble shoot this, I have used `\nocite{*}` option after `bibliography` command. Still it does not work.
2. On the Appendix page, a header of the `chap4` {Header used in chap4.tex } is displayed.
3. In the Content(Index) page of the output file, the page number for Appendix is incorrectly shown.

I have tried almost all the troubleshooting steps I could think of. Still, the problem persists.

I attach my main tex file for reference:

```
\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{epsfig}
\usepackage{url}
\geometry{verbose,a4paper,tmargin=25mm,bmargin=25mm,lmargin=32mm,rmargin=32mm}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{5}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{5}
\onehalfspacing
\usepackage{txfonts}
%\usefont{T1}{tnr}{m}{sl}
\makeatletter
\makeatother
\renewcommand{\contentsname}{TABLE OF CONTENTS}
\renewcommand\bibname{REFERENCES}
\usepackage[authoryear,round]{natbib}
\renewcommand{\chaptername}{CHAPTER}
\newtheorem{definition}{Definition}

% Title Page
\input{titlepage}


\frontmatter
\pagenumbering{roman}

\input {cert}
\input{ack}
\input{abs}

\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic}

\tableofcontents
%\setcounter{page}{1}

\input{company}

\input{ch1}
\input{newchap}
\input{ch2}
\input{ch3}
\input{ch4}

\setcitestyle{numbers}
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{REFERENCES}
\bibliographystyle{kluwer}
\bibliography{ref}
\include{appendix}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Regarding your first question: Have you run BibTeX after running LaTeX, and followed that up with two more LaTeX runs? Incidentally, why do you load `natbib` with the option `authoryear` and then issue the instruction `\setcitestyle{numbers}`? Which citation call-out style do you want? Separately, as `kluwer` is one of the bibliography styles provided by the `harvard` citation management package, you should load the `har2nat` package (after loading `natbib`).